# Windows 10 Universal Apps: What alternatives are available to NATIVELY send and/or receive SMS messages?

Tags: sms, store, windows-10, uwp

In my research I've found various code examples but what I've found thus far doesn't allow me to publish an app that would use such capabilities. Is there a "legal" method that uses the NATIVE device capabilities (so, no external service such as Twilio) to programmatically send or receive SMS messages via my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have OEM privileges to do do what you like. Which normal mortals cannot obtain. See the sample and docs at https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SmsSendAndReceive for more info, but unless you are TMobile||Verizon||ATT||insert big operator here, you won't be able to do it.

Sorry sir...

Comment: I figured it would be something like that. Thanks!